# How can I snap to points with the measure tool in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, measurement

I want for example to measure the diameter of a circle but I could not find how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The diameter of a circle is the same as its width (and height).  So technicaly, you don't actually have to measure anything, because if you select the circle with the Select Tool <kbd>S</kbd> you can see its diameter displayed in the controls bar along the top.

[image]

As for snapping, you can use the snapping options with the Measure Tool. Just switch on the snapping options you need. You can snap the measure tool to the rotation centre, and the path. This will give you the radius. The diameter of a circle is twice the radius.

[image]

Another possibility is to open the XML editor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> , and select the circle. The radius will be shown. All you need to do is double the radius to get the diameter.  This is useful if you don't want to include the stroke as part of the diameter (if a stroke is applied).

[image]

Even if an object is not an SVG circle (which will not show a radius like that above), one could easily remove the stroke temporarily and check its width in the controls bar. then apply the stroke again. Or even simply subtract the stroke width from the circle width. It's just simple arithmetic

Comment: @s.ouchene - yes. Anyway I've added an edit to deal with that scenario.

Comment: Yes, I was about to suggest looking at the XML editor but that will work only in the case of a circle object (not a circle that was converted to a path; which cannot be accurately represented using Bezier curves).

Comment: But, saying that the diameter of a circle is the same as the width is not correct. You can check that by creating a circle, increase its stroke size, check the radius from the XML Editor, multiply it by 2, then compare it with the width value shown in the toolbar. You will see that increasing strokes size will change the width but not the radius (hence diameter).

Comment: @s.ouchene even if an object is not an SVG circle, one could easily remove the stroke temporarily and check its width.  then apply the stroke again. Or even simply subtract the stroke width from the circle width. It's just simple arithmetic. I'm not going to write a book about this, I think it's fairly self evident TBH.

Comment: You're right, please add that to your answer, IMO, that will make things much more clear for new users.

Comment: @s.ouchene - done